# Jquery UI - Bind the Selectable on future elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a container div ".thumbList" that contains thumbnails as < li >. I have bind the jquery UI selectable with it like this:

```
$(".thumbList").selectable();
```

Now, when I click on some other tab, the container div changes with a new container div (same class .thumbList) using Ajax.

I have to apply the selectable on the new container as well. Right now what I am doing is to re-assign the binding on the element. But there are lots of codes that i am using within the selectable code, and by using this again on ajax response, I am duplicating the code in this page again. That is not good for maintainability of code. I think this can be solved with ".on" but not sure about the event that will bind it for page load and ajax load complete both.

Comment: Keep selectable code on the main page. After you do the ajax request and push those into page have the code as $(".thumbList").selectable();

Comment: as i mentioned, the code is not just the `$("thumbList").selectable(); `

Its:

`$(".thumbList").selectable({
 filter:"li",
 autoRefresh: true,
 stop: function(){
  selectedItemArr = [];
  selectedItemIdArr = [];
  $( ".ui-selected", this ).each(function(){
   selectedItemArr.push($(this).attr("id"));
   selectedItemIdArr.push($(this).data("id"));
  });
  $("#selectedCount").text("[ " + selectedItemArr.length + " ]");
  updateSelectedList($(".thumbList").data("type"));
 }
});`


Do I'll have to duplicate these all lines?

Comment: Gaurav, I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep `$(".thumbList").selectable();` in a separate function in main page.

```
function iniThumbList(){
    $(".thumbList").selectable( /* wt ever the your remaining code */);
}
```

After document initialization call  iniThumbList(); This is the initial behavior of your code. 
Now After the ajax completion when you have new content inside the DOM call iniThumbList();
This way you don't have to repeat the code and it's easy to read it even at a later time.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html"
    })
    .done(function( html ) {
          $( "#results" ).append( html );
          iniThumbList();
    });
```